# Add forward or reverse counter for subsets of data, depending on first record's value

Tags: r

I have a dataset "Stops" that looks like this:

```
ID    response    startno
1     Yes         1
1     Yes         
1     Yes       
1     No
2     Yes   
2     Yes
2     No
2     No          1
```

I would like to add a counter that starts either on the first or last record for each ID, depending on which has the "1" in startno:

```
ID    response    startno    counter
1     Yes         1           1
1     Yes                     2
1     Yes                     3
1     No                      4
2     Yes                     4
2     Yes                     3
2     No                      2
2     No          1           1
```

The starting record will always be the first or last record.  I used this to get a forward count:

```
Stops$counter<-ave(Stops$ID,Stops$ID,FUN=seq_along)
```

But I am lost as to how to have it check to see whether it should go forward or backward.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: add reproducible data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not sort the dataframe according to `ID` and `startno` (reversed)? You can then apply your `ave`:

```
within(Stops[order(Stops$ID, -Stops$startno),], counter <- ave(ID,ID, FUN=seq_along))
```

Result:

```
  ID response startno counter
1  1      Yes       1       1
2  1      Yes       0       2
3  1      Yes       0       3
4  1       No       0       4
8  2       No       1       1
5  2      Yes       0       2
6  2      Yes       0       3
7  2       No       0       4
```

Comment: This works - thanks!  It's funny because in SAS sorting is everything but I didn't think to do it here.  I'd vote up the answer but apparently my reputation is too piddly to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just be:

```
 Stops$counter<-ave(Stops$ID,Stops$ID,
       FUN=function(x) if (x[1]=="1" ) { seq_along(x)} else {rev(seq_along(x))} )

> Stops
  ID response startno counter
1  1      Yes       1       1
2  1      Yes               2
3  1      Yes               3
4  1       No               4
5  2      Yes               4
6  2      Yes               3
7  2       No               2
8  2       No       1       1
```

When programming with `ave` you need to think one group at a time and realize that you will be retruning a vector exactly as long as the "group length", so if seq_along is good for the simple case then using if to retrun one of two alternatives is pretty simple to implement.

Comment: This is helpful (I am newish to R and still have trouble manipulating data), but I think it's not quite right. Is it possible that it's working because the first ID happens to be 1?  In other words, I don't think it's reading "startno" as it should.  I'll continue to work on it and post an update if I figure it out on my own.

Comment: You wrote: "The starting record will always be the first or last record." So I don't need to test whether it is the last record if it isn't the first record. Post a counter example if you think it's not behaving properly.

Comment: @DWin, just replace `ave(Stops$ID,Stops$ID,...` to `ave(Stops$startno,Stops$ID,...`.

Comment: I am not sure where I am supposed to add the counter example - in the original post?  I tried to here but it didn't work.  Anyway, when I added a third observer with startno of 1 in the first record it continued to count down.  But it looks like I'm set now.  Thanks!